# What -A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited Iptables line does exactly?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, icmp

I have been reading RedHat `iptables` documentation but can't figure out what does the following line do:

```
... -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The `REJECT` target rejects the packet. If you do not specify which ICMP message to reject with, the server by default will send back ICMP port unreachable (type 3, code 3).

`--reject-with` modifies this behaviour to send a specific ICMP message back to the source host. You can find information about `--reject-with` and the available rejection messages in [`man iptables`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables):

> #### REJECT
>
> This is used to send back an error packet in response to the matched packet: otherwise it is equivalent to DROP so it is a terminating TARGET, ending rule traversal. This target is only valid in the INPUT, FORWARD and OUTPUT chains, and user-defined chains which are only called from those chains. The following option controls the nature of the error packet returned:
>
> ```
> --reject-with type
> ```
>
> The type given can be:
>
> - icmp-net-unreachable
> - icmp-host-unreachable
> - icmp-port-unreachable
> - icmp-proto-unreachable
> - icmp-net-prohibited
> - icmp-host-prohibited or
> - icmp-admin-prohibited (*)
>
> which return the appropriate ICMP error message (port-unreachable is the default). The option tcp-reset can be used on rules which only match the TCP protocol: this causes a TCP RST packet to be sent back. This is mainly useful for blocking ident (113/tcp) probes which frequently occur when sending mail to broken mail hosts (which won't accept your mail otherwise).
>
> (*) Using icmp-admin-prohibited with kernels that do not support it will result in a plain DROP instead of REJECT

Comment: Can or should I rate limit ICMP replies so as to avoid my server being used in an amplification attack?  How would the rules look like?  (e.g. 1/sec ICMP net-unreachable, rest DROP)?